# Metabase running through cmd, when logout dashboard is not getting saved

Tags: java, metabase

I've ran metabase java jar file and start creating dashboard, after logout and closing cmd.

Again run jar file, but it is asking to add login and DB details. My work is not saved?

Answer (score 0):

Team,

Only if it works on the server, then only the data will be saved, otherwise it will load like a new session, Yesterday i came to know.